# ctk frame image exeeding its boundries

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, customtkinter

I made a CTK frame with width, height, and corner radius as 40. I displayed the CTK image sized as 50 in it. The image is exceeding its boundaries and displayed in a square shape outside the frame. I tried to keep the image inside the label, then too it didn't work. it is not a error, a problem. I made a circul